# How do I say the following statement about probability in a formal probability theoretic way

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose I have a random variable $X$ with $\{x_1,\ldots, x_n\}$ many possible instantiation.

I wish to to say, for example, $x_1$ takes up the majority of the probability weight. I.E

$\mathbb{P}(X=x_1)$ is "much higher" than other $\mathbb{P}(X=x_i)$, $i\neq 1$.

What different ways or examples can I say this formally. Or more explicitly, how do I characterize such a property in probabilistic term.

Cheers

Comment: What’s wrong with the way you’ve already put that? How are you going to use that?

Comment: Since "much higher" isn't really quantitative, I think keeping it the way you wrote it is fine.  Of course, if you are trying to actually use this property for anything, you'll need to make the meaning more precise.

Comment: @lulu indeed i need to use it in a formal argument and im trying to find a suitable formal characterization of this property

Comment: But of course we have no idea what formal meaning you have in mind.  My guess is that this will depend on context.  There simply isn't any formal meaning behind "much higher".  Figure out what property you require for the given application and  state that property.  Maybe that will be something that generalizes in an interesting way, and maybe not.

Comment: Just looking at what you wrote, maybe all you want is that $P(x_1)>.5$  as that's what "takes up the majority of the probability" means.  But, of course, you could have $P(x_1)=.50001$ and $P(x_2)=.49000001$, with all the others very small, so it wouldn't necessarily be true that $P(x_1)$ is "much higher" than the others.

Answer (score 0):

If
$$
  \mathbb{P}(X=x_1)\ge\mathbb{P}(X=x_k) \quad \text{for all $k\in\{2,\ldots,n\}$},
$$
then $x_1$ is called a [mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)) of the law of $X$. If even
$$
  \mathbb{P}(X=x_1)>\mathbb{P}(X=x_k) \quad \text{for all $k\in\{2,\ldots,n\}$},
$$
then $x_1$ is the unique mode of the law of $X$ and this law is called unimodal.

However, I am not aware of a common terminology for the case in which the mode of distribution "takes up the majority of the probability weight". This notion would have to be made more precise anyway.